# Multithreaded Video Converter on Mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, encoding

Is there an app for Mac that can distribute a single video encoding job to several thread to utilize the full potential of the system?

I used an application called iFlicks to do video encoding, and as far as I know, it's single-threaded, so even though it can use all my CPU time, it cannot squeeze the best performance out of my system.

I am using a 15" MacBook Pro with Retina Display.

Also, I knew that there were multithreaded ffmpeg implementation, but I can't figure out how to use that. If anyone could help, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Compressor](http://www.apple.com/finalcutpro/compressor/) by Apple not only one of the most fully featured encoders around and fully supports multiple threads, it even supports distributed encoding so that more than one Mac can work on a single job.

Comment: Compressor is multithreaded? Really, never noticed that.

Comment: Yup - "With Apple Qmaster features now built into Compressor, you can quickly use available cores in your Mac — as well as other Mac computers on your network — to speed up encoding jobs." You can send that video workhorse to me anytime you need it tuned up - encodes are the only time I see my Air really break a sweat these days :_)

Answer (score 3):

[Handbreak](http://handbrake.fr) converts videos to  H.264(x264), MPEG-4 and MPEG-2 (libav) and uses multiple cores.

Comment: thanks for answering, but after testing multiple solutions, Compressor is much faster and can distribute jobs to multiple Macs, which works great. But it's a paid solution, and it's better to keep this answer here so anyone looking for a free solution can find this.

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from using AppGeeker [MOV MP4 Converter for Mac](http://www.ilikemall.com/how-to/convert-mp4-to-mov-mac.html), it is a nice little multithreaded media conversion tool that can convert almost every video format on Mac.